# Dashed line and Wireframe

Tags: transparency, freestyle, wireframe

I'm trying to render a cube with 2 additional vertical edges on a one of the faces.
I use the wireframe modifier for making faces transparent and freestyle for making the dashed edges.
The issue is the fact that these 2 dashed edges become non-dashed in render.
Can I somehow make the edges to be dashed while the wireframe modifier is applied?

[image]

[image: The cube]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Wireframe modifier *and* Freestyle seems to me to be using two conflicting tools to do the same job, The modifier doubles up existing edges, which overlap in the Freestyle output.

At first sight, unless you have special reasons, an option would be to remove the wireframe modifier, and leave the transparency to Freestyle.

[image]

Here, the cube's material is set to be transparent so no faces are shown, and the 'Visibility' selection criterion is removed for  the solid Freestyle Line Set, so it can be seen through the cube.

[image]

For the face transparency to be effective in EEVEE, the Alpha has to be set away from 'Opaque' in the material's Settings panel.

As @Gorgious has commented, for EEVEE, it's probably better to set Alpha than Transmission on the material.

If you need to see one object inside another, and have it occlude the Freestyle lines (while they are *not* occluded by the containing object), this is one possible logic:

- In order *not* to have the internal object display Freestyle, separate the Freestyle objects into a different Collection, and add a 'Collection' constraint to the Line Set selection criteria.
- To have the outer object's Freestyle occluded by the inner object, you can use a [QI range](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html#visibility), which makes the display of a Freestyle stroke contingent on the number of surfaces between the edge and the eye point.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me, please, how can I set up the transparency of the material?
I changed the transmission from 0 to 1, but for some reason any object placed inside the cube is not visible.

Comment: Have you changed the blend mode of the material in the settings foldout ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, I've selected 'Alpha Clip'.

Comment: Try changing the "alpha" value to 0 instead of the transmission value

Comment: @Gorgious Now it works fine, but the issue is the visibility of some edges. The back edges of the cube are overlapping an inner figure.

Comment: @MikhailNono .. see edit..